# Send message from windows form app to the Unity

Tags: winforms, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way for sending and receiving message from unity app to the windows app. All the solution which I found was just work for unity or windows.
I am looking for a reliable solution. 
My windows app is not Universal Windows. It is windows form application because I need to be backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can always communicate between Apps using UDP by implementing your own Client/Server.
Then it doesn't matter what kind of language or framework you are using.